# Django Rest Framework: Why does PrimaryKeyRelatedField document as a string in the schema when read_only?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, swagger-ui, openapi

I have a serializer with a PrimaryKeyRelatedField:

```
field_name = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ModelClass.objects.all(), read_only=False)
```

With this setup, the Schema properly identifies the parameter as an integer (the PK). But, when I change to:

```
field_name = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
```

(it will not let you specify `queryset` and `read_only` at the same time) then the parameter is identified as a string in the Schema.

Why would this be? Is this correct/expected behavior or perhaps a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had banged my head on this one long enough to post on SO, but as I've continued to dig into it I think I am making some progress.

At `rest_framework/schemas/openapi.py:380` inside of `map_field()` you find the following:

```
if isinstance(field, serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    model = getattr(field.queryset, 'model', None)
    if model is not None:
        model_field = model._meta.pk
        if isinstance(model_field, models.AutoField):
            return {'type': 'integer'}
```

RelatedField won't let you specify a queryset when read_only=True though, so then the "model" in the above code snippet is always None when read_only=True, and you end up getting type="string" at the bottom of the map_field function.

So this explains why it is currently happening, and seems like a bug in DRF, but now I guess I just need to look into what the appropriate fix would be.

I've opened up a corresponding issue against DRF: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/7427